# jar dependencies not packaged on a Tomcat project on IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a Tomcat project I am trying to run on IntelliJ Community Edition for Windows. The project was originally created in Eclipse on Windows.

The project is based on Jersey and built with Maven and has a /lib folder containing several .jar dependency files. These dependencies are created internally and need to be loaded from the .jar files for now.

I am trying to run the project using this configuration:

[image: Run configuration]

Tomcat seems to be starting properly, but I get this error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/some/dependency/somepackage/SomeClassException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:236)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:744)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:404)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.urbanlaunchpad.flocktracker.flocktrackerprojectmodels.ProjectException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    ... 63 more

Oct 18, 2021 7:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /flocktracker threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.some.dependency.somepackage.SomeClassException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:236)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:744)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:404)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

The error lists classes contained in the .jar dependencies. The project doesn't seem to be compiling the .jar dependencies into the deployed .war file.

On the Project Structure menu, the /lib folder is listed as a library:
[image: Project Structure - libraries]

And on the same menu, on the modules section, the lib folder is listed with scope "compile":

[image: Project Structure - modules]

But, on the Maven panel, on the list of dependencies, neither the /lib folder or the specific .jar files are listed as dependencies.

[image: Maven panel]

I can also confirm this running `mvn dependency:tree`. The output doesn't list any of the classes inside the .jar file.

Is there something I might be missing?

Edit:

As requested, here's the pom.xml file. It has no references to the .jar files, but it works this way in Eclipse:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>come.some.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzly-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina &ndash;&gt;
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                    <version>10.1.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Your build path and your classpath are different things.

Comment: Why do you have a lib directory? Use them as dependencies... Also if you create a WAR can you show how you are doing that? Please show the pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, I added the pom.xml file. In Eclipse, there are no references to the lib folder or the .jar files, but it works in Tomcat. The .jar files have to be loaded from local files from now as they are not going to be hosted in a remote repository any time soon.